# Casting string type column percentage to a decimal

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on this dataset having two columns(`date->date`, `sales_%->string`) -

| date | sales_% |
| --- | --- |
| 20/12/2021 | 50% |
| 21/12/2021 | 29% |
| 22/12/2021 | 60% |
| 23/12/2021 | 12% |
| 24/12/2021 | 75% |
| 25/12/2021 | 28% |

I want to convert the `sales_%` column to a decimal value(by dividing the `%` by 100).
The desired output should look like -

| date | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 20/12/2021 | 0.5 |
| 21/12/2021 | 0.29 |
| 22/12/2021 | 0.6 |
| 23/12/2021 | 0.12 |
| 24/12/2021 | 0.75 |
| 25/12/2021 | 0.28 |

This is what i have tried -

```py
spark.sql("""select date, cast(cast(replace("sales_%",'%','') as integer)/100) as decimal(2,2)) from table_name""")
```

I am getting nulls. Let me know if anyone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing column name as `"sales_%"` which is interpreted as literal string by Spark. You need to use back-ticks instead of quotes. Also, there is no need cast to integer before division by 100. Try this:

```py
spark.sql("""
    select  date, 
            cast(replace(`sales_%`,'%','')/100 as decimal(2,2)) as sales
    from    table_name
""").show()

#+----------+-----+
#|      date|sales|
#+----------+-----+
#|20/12/2021| 0.50|
#|21/12/2021| 0.29|
#|22/12/2021| 0.60|
#|23/12/2021| 0.12|
#|24/12/2021| 0.75|
#|25/12/2021| 0.28|
#+----------+-----+
```